# 3D-PDF Error when adding 3Dviews to media

Tags: errors, media9

I am facing problems when I want to add 3Dviews to my media. I cannot compile the following code, getting an error 'undefined control sequence'. But without the line `3Dviews=test.vws,` it works.

The strange thing is that this code had been working fine before I installed the newest MikTex distribution and also updated all packages... I would be thankful for any hints, can you help me please?

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1cm, right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{media9}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\centering
\includemedia[
label=converter3degreelines,
width=\textwidth,
height=\textheight,
activate=pagevisible,
deactivate=pageinvisible,
3Dviews=test.vws,
3Dmenu
]{
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{test.png}
}{test.u3d}
\end{document}
```

The test.vws file contains the following:

```
VIEW=Default
    COO=4.675      -4.675       4.675
    C2C=0            0      80.9734
    ROO=6.1057
    ROLL=0
    ORTHO=0.081891

    PART=Mesh1
        RENDERMODE=Wireframe
    END
END
```

The error message from the Log is the following:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Missing number before '*'.
l.20 }{test.u3d}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

The file list from the .log is:

```
*File List*
article.cls 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
geometry.sty 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
keyval.sty 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
ifpdf.sty 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
ifvtex.sty 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
ifxetex.sty 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
graphicx.sty 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
ltxcmds.sty 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
media9.sty 2013/08/16 v0.30 acrobat-9/X compatible media
expl3.sty 2013/07/28 v4582 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
l3names.sty 2012/12/07 v4346 L3 Namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
etex.sty 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
l3basics.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Basic definitions
l3expan.sty 2013/07/24 v4565 L3 Argument expansion
l3tl.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Token lists
l3seq.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Sequences and stacks
l3int.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Integers
l3quark.sty 2013/07/21 v4564 L3 Quarks
l3prg.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Control structures
l3clist.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Comma separated lists
l3token.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental token manipulation
l3prop.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Property lists
l3msg.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Messages
l3file.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 File and I/O operations
l3skip.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Dimensions and skips
l3keys.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
l3fp.sty 2013/07/09 v4521 L3 Floating points
l3box.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental boxes
l3coffins.sty 2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Coffin code layer
l3color.sty 2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support
l3luatex.sty 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
l3candidates.sty 2013/07/24 v4576 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
l3regex.sty 2013/07/24 v4576 L3 Experimental regular expressions
l3tl-build.sty 2011/12/08 v3039 L3 Experimental token list construction
l3tl-analysis.sty 2011/12/08 v3039 L3 Experimental token lists analysis
l3str.sty 2013/07/24 v4576 L3 Experimental strings
l3flag.sty 2011/12/08 v3039 L3 Experimental flags
l3str-convert.sty 2013/01/08 v4339 L3 Experimental string encoding conversio
ns
l3keys2e.sty 2013/07/28 v4582 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
xparse.sty 2013/07/28 v4582 L3 Experimental document command parser
atbegshi.sty 2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
hyperref.sty 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty 2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty 2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
hobsub.sty 2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
intcalc.sty 2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty 2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty 2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
bitset.sty 2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty 2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty 2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
hopatch.sty 2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty 2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty 2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
refcount.sty 2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
hycolor.sty 2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
auxhook.sty 2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
pd1enc.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
url.sty 2006/04/12 ver 3.3 Verb mode for urls, etc.
hpdftex.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty 2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty 2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
grfext.sty 2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
nameref.sty 2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty 2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
mediatest.out
mediatest.out
test.png Graphic file (type png)
***********
```

Comment: Please edit in the exact text of the error. Also, add `\listfiles` to your input and edit in the `File list` from the `.log`.

Comment: Likely unrelated to your problem, but there are conflicting driver options in your source. Add `dvipdfmx` as class option (`\documentclass[landscape,dvipdfm,dvipdfmx]{article}`) and remove other driver options in the source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem are the tabs in the .vws file,

```
COO=0.2899417579174042 [TAB] 0 [TAB] -4.275146484375
```

causing the error message stated in the question, or

```
[TAB]PART=Mesh1
```

causing an error like

```
! LaTeX error: "kernel/key-unknown"
! 
! The key 'media9/views/    PART' is unknown and is being ignored.
```

Replacing the `[TAB]` by whitespaces solves the problem.

Furthermore, the use of comments, like

```
%    PART=Mesh1
```

also causes an error:

```
! LaTeX error: "kernel/key-unknown"
! 
! The key 'media9/views/%    PART' is unknown and is being ignored.
```

Removing all tabs and comment lines worked for me.

Comment: Today's update of `media9` (v. 0.31) correctly treats multiple spaces including spaces, comments and empty lines in 3D views files.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to changes in the `expl3` package loaded by `media9`. A package update should resolve this issue:

```
tlmgr update --all
```

The current version [2013/08/16 v. 0.30] of media9 is not yet available through MiKTeX package manager.

TeXLive is usually faster at package updates than MiKTeX.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you suggested, I installed TeXLive instead of MikTeX and made an update for all packages. The version of media9 package on my system is [0.30]. Unfortunately, the problem remains the same.

Comment: I tested the dice example from the media9 doc which uses a views file and I had no problems compiling it with version 0.30. Please proceed as suggested by Joseph, adding `\listfiles` to the top of your `*.tex` source file and posting the `*File List*` section from the `*.log` file. Probably you are still using MiKTeX. When the error occurs during compilation, hit `q` on the keyboard to finalise the LaTeX run.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. I compared the dice.vws to my test.vws and replaced the whitspaces in the lines `COO=4.675    -4.675       4.675` and
`C2C=0            0      80.9734` by only one space and now it works.
by only one space,

Comment: Sorry, further editing of my last comment was denied - so it works now, caused by the whitespaces, but i have no clue why. I am quite new here, can you tell me how to state this question is answered? Just by checking this answer, or by posting a second answer, adressing the whitespace problem?

Comment: You may click the checkmark left to the answer, if you wish. But you don't need to, because the reason for the failure was a different one (the one you found out). You may answer your own question, stating your solution to the problem and accept this one as the best answer.

Comment: @Nikolaus: Your finding that multiple spaces caused the problem would be a valuable information for other users. Consider making this an answer! You may even remove the 'answered' status from my answer.